# Remove marker in R shiny app created for reactive dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

In my shiny app data is loaded from PostgreSQL database. Database can be updated during session from the app, therefore data is loaded to reactive dataframe. It has lon/lat and is displayed on leaflet map. I would like marker from map to be deleted with clicking on it. Without reactive data it works in appropriate way.
I am looking forward help with understanding what is wrong. Sample code is below (markers not deleted after removeMarker)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

ui<-fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map1")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  getPoints0 <- function(){
    mydf <- head(quakes,10)
    mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(myid = row_number())
    return(mydf)
  }

  df<-reactiveVal(getPoints0());

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
   leaflet(data=df()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        lng = ~long,
        lat = ~lat,
        layerId = ~myid,
        label = paste0("LayerId = ",df()$myid))
  })

  observe(
    leafletProxy("map1") %>%
      removeMarker(input$map1_marker_click$id)
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the `?removeMarker` documentation and noticed that `layerId` argument asks for a character vector -

> layerId:  **character** vector; the layer id(s) of the item to remove

I made the following change and it worked for me -

```
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data=df()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        lng = ~long,
        lat = ~lat,
        layerId = ~as.character(myid), # here's the change
        label = paste0("LayerId = ", df()$myid))
  })
```

You could also make the change upstream in `getPoints0()` i.e. `myid = as.character(row_number())` so that `myid` is consistently a `character` downstream.

PS: Great reproducible question!

Comment: thank you! It works! It is some magic not to crash without reactiveness case!